# Rest API- How to get Json API Request call and send Json Response using c#?

Tags: c#

My requirements are

1. create API to get the user information(JSON request) from other system, update those information to database.
2. After update want to send the JSON response back.

Please help me to achieve this.

My controller:

```
namespace CT.API.User
{
    public class UserController : CTControllerBase
    {
        //API
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult USerApiTest()
        {
            // to handle the code
       }
    }
}
```

Request Details:

```
{"REQLEN":4,"REQDTL":[{"ID":"48490","UserName":"Test1","Password":"Test1"},{"ID":"48491","UserName":"Test2","Password":"Test2"}]}
```

Reponse Details:

```
{"RESLEN":4,"RESDTL":[{"ID":"48490","Status":"Success"},{"ID":"48491","Status":"Fail"}]}
```

Comment: Is the Question alone about how to manipulate the Json? What Framework are you Wirkung with .net Core,.net4XX,...?

Comment: I'm using entity framework model. I want to build the API to meet the mentioned requirements, please help me

Comment: well if you're using EF then your requirements are automated by EF itself, just right click on your project, add new WEB API using EF with default action then you're almost done

Comment: What do you want to check? If the User exists or If the password is valid?

Comment: How to get Json API Request call and send Json Response using c#? Please provide code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, this is what you Need:

```
 namespace CT.API.User
{
    public class UserController : CTControllerBase
    {
        //API
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ResponseModel USerApiTest([FromBody] RequestModel request)
        {
            // to handle the code
            ResponseModel res = new ResponseModel ();
            List<UserResult> results = new List<UserResult>();
            foreach( var user in request.ReqDtl)
            {
                   if(//Status should be Success)
                   {
                        results.Add( new UserResult{ ID=user.ID,Status = "Success"};
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                         results.Add(new UserResult{ ID=user.ID, Status = "Fail"};
                  }
             }

             res.ResDtl= results.ToArray();
             res.ResLen=request.ReqLen;
             return res;

        }
    }

    public class RequestModel
    {
        public int ReqLen { get; set;}
        public User[] ReqDtl { get; set; }
    }

     public class ResponseModel 
     {
         public int ResLen { get; set; }
         public UserResult[] ResDtl { get; set; }

     }

    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserResult
    {
          public int ID { get; set; }
          public string Status { get; set; }
     }
}
```